# What part of OpenAI API request payload is limited by the max amount tokens?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

I kinda understand how to count tokens out of characters, but what do I actually have to count?
If I have a payload like this:

```json
{
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  "temperature": 1,
  "max_tokens": 400,
  "presence_penalty": 0.85,
  "frequency_penalty": 0.85,
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "prompt"
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "message"
    },
    // tens of messages
  ]
}
```

Do I have to count tokens out of it **entirely**? Or do I have to count it in `"messages"` only? If so, do I have to count all the json syntax characters, like spacebars, brackets and commas too? What about `"role"` and `"content"` keys? What about `"role"` value?
Or I have to simply concat all the `"content"` values into a single string and count tokens based only on it? (this is what I *would like* to get as an answer, hehe)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding and calculations, all the tokens in the list provided in `"messages"` are counted. This includes the keys "role" and "content" and their values but does not include spaces, brackets, commas, and quotes.

I use the following script provided by OpenAI to calculate the number of tokens in my input. I have modified the script to calculate the cost involved with the input for multiple messages (not the output response) and it's been fairly accurate for me.

```py
import json
import os
import tiktoken
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

def num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"):
    """Return the number of tokens used by a list of messages."""
    try:
        encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(model)
    except KeyError:
        print("Warning: model not found. Using cl100k_base encoding.")
        encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")
    if model in {
        "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
        "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
        "gpt-4-0613",
        "gpt-4-32k-0613",
        }:
        tokens_per_message = 3
        tokens_per_name = 1
    elif model == "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301":
        tokens_per_message = 4  # every message follows <|start|>{role/name}\n{content}<|end|>\n
        tokens_per_name = -1  # if there's a name, the role is omitted
    elif "gpt-3.5-turbo" in model:
        print("Warning: gpt-3.5-turbo may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-3.5-turbo-0613.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")
    elif "gpt-4" in model:
        print("Warning: gpt-4 may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-4-0613.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-4-0613")
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f"""num_tokens_from_messages() is not implemented for model {model}. See https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/chatml.md for information on how messages are converted to tokens."""
        )
    num_tokens = 0
    for message in messages:
        num_tokens += tokens_per_message
        for key, value in message.items():
            num_tokens += len(encoding.encode(value))
            if key == "name":
                num_tokens += tokens_per_name
    num_tokens += 3  # every reply is primed with <|start|>assistant<|message|>
    return num_tokens

convo_lens = []

for ex in dataset: #Your list of inputs
    messages = ex["messages"]
    convo_lens.append(num_tokens_from_messages(messages))

n_input_tokens_in_dataset = sum(min(4096, length) for length in convo_lens)
print(f"Input portion of the data has ~{n_input_tokens_in_dataset} tokens")

# costs as of Aug 29 2023.
costs = {
    "gpt-4-0613": {
        "input" : 0.03,
        "output": 0.06
    },
    "gpt-4-32k-0613": {
        "input" : 0.06,
        "output": 0.12
    },
    "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613": {
        "input": 0.0015,
        "output": 0.002
    },

    "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613": {
        "input": 0.003,
        "output": 0.004
    }
}

# We select GPT 3.5 turbo here
print(f"Cost of inference: ${(n_input_tokens_in_dataset/1000) * costs['gpt-3.5-turbo-0613']['input']}")
```